# Showing a point on a map when latitude and longitude are given

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, latitude-longitude, folium

I have a large dataset from which I am interested in this part:

```
temp    lat    long
7.1     47     13
19      49     16
```

I tried using folium:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
MarkerCluster()
map2 = folium.Map(location=[47.031, 13.001999], tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', zoom_start=11)

marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map2)
```

But I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.

Then I tried using bokeh by copy-pasting an Internet example just to see if it works:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import (
  GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, Circle, LogColorMapper, BasicTicker, ColorBar,
    DataRange1d, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool
)
from bokeh.models.mappers import ColorMapper, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis5
```

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.88, lng=-122.23, map_type="roadmap", zoom=6)

```
plot = GMapPlot(
    x_range=bokeh.Range1d(), y_range=bokeh.Range1d(), map_options=map_options
)
plot.title.text = "Hey look! It's a scatter plot on a map!"
show(plot)
```

But I get `NameError: name 'bokeh' is not defined`.

Is there any other way to plot a point or to fix the errors?

Comment: Import `Range1d` from `bokeh.models` and use the model just as that without the `bokeh.` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your Folium example with the following code :

```
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

m = folium.Map(location=[47.031, 13.001999], zoom_start=5)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)

folium.Marker(
    location=[47.031, 13.001999],
    popup='Add popup text here.',
    icon=folium.Icon(color='green', icon='ok-sign'),
).add_to(marker_cluster)

m
```

It works just well :

[image: Result]

Maybe there is another part of your code which was triggering the EOS error. An EOS error usually occurs because of missing commas, parenthesis etc.

If you are interested in the different types of folium Markers, there is an [official Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/MarkerCluster.ipynb) with interesting examples.